How to reload/restart/kill VSCode server/service/process in Linux/Ubuntu?
I use VSCode in the Remote SSH extension. VSCode oftentimes hangs as memory usage ups, so for the each time I need to restart the VSCode through FILE -> Exit to close the instance entirely (including the non-SSH sessions which I don't want to close altogether.)
When the computer hanged on a Mongodb for example, I can simply do sudo systemctl restart mongod to force-restart the deamon/process to release the memory usage, cpu usage locks. I need something like this for VSCode. Maybe non a deamon but for a parent process? But I haven't figured out which. So please tell me how. Thank you.

Edit
I could kill the process on the computer. In the above example, it would be kill -9 3221. (to kill the parent process)
Good, but what is the process name but not rather a PID? (because easier to kill even when the computer is hanging where you cannot launch htop)
I think it installed through snapd but I'm not familiar with the package manager.

you can kill the process using name like this pkill -f "code"

You can kill code-server with :
pkill -f -u $EUID /code-server

